# Division of 2 numbers and saving the result in array

Tags: c, arrays, division

I have been working on some code, but it looks like my logic is not right.
I am trying to make a program that divides number (a) into equal parts (b) (if that is possible) and then save those results, along with the initial dividing number, into an array. Something like this:

1. 20/2=10     [10][10]
2. 20/3=6    [8][6][6]

So I here is my code:

```
for (i=0; i<b; i++)
{
  if (a%b)
  {
    array[i]=a/b;
  }
  else
  {
    array[0]=(a/b)+(a%b);
    array[i+1]=a/b;
  }                 
  printf("\n\nIn range %d there are %d\n\n",i,Sub_arr_len[i]);
}
```

It looks like the first case is working, but the second is not and I don't know why. Any ideas?

Comment: Surely `20/3=6 [8][6][6]` would be more"equal" as `20/3=6 [7][7][6]`?

Comment: I am trying to get the first one having the equal part+a%b, and the rest of the string just equal parts.

Comment: In that case, your program is working?

Comment: @WeatherVane Why would you say that?

Comment: @Childishforlife because OP asks for equal parts. In his example, the difference between the splits is 2, in mine only 1, therefore my split is "more equal".

Comment: @WeatherVane Oh, I was interpreting his reference to "equal parts" differently. I thought he just meant to have no remainder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line

`array[0]=(a/b)+(a%b);`

Your first array element is the integer division, plus the remainder. For any division with a remainder, your program will not work. It instead stores the integer division in all of the elements apart from the first, where it is summed with the remainder.

To combat this I would write most of the code into an if statement testing if the modulus is 0 or not. I assume you don't want to save any array if your division doesn't result in equal parts, so you should only do what you are currently doing if `a%b = 0`.

Comment: I want to save arrays even if there is remainder but array[0] should be equal to remainder+integer division. Just like I said in the description: 20/3=6 [8][6][6]

Comment: The integer division in this case is 6. The remainder is 2. 6+2 = 8, which is the value stored in array[0].

Comment: so you think this is corectly done and I get correct examples 1 and 2 from the description right?

Comment: I believe so? 8+6+6 = 20. 6 is the integer division and 2 the remainder, so you have in your array 8,6,6.

Comment: I am working on bigger MPI project and I thought my logic is wrong here because when I have remainder my program is not working right, but it looks like I will have to check somewhere else.